# Django - getting the original class name in abstact method

Tags: django, django-orm

What I am trying to do is best described by the following example:

```
class MyAbstractClass(models.Model):
    abstract_field = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def abstract_method(self):
         # THE ISSUE LIES IN THE LINE BELOW 
         ParentClass.objects.filter(..).update(....)
         return self

class InheritedClass(MyAbstractClass):
     # Field

def my_view(request):
    obj = InheritedClass.objects.get(id=1)
    obj.save()
    return obj
```

So basically, the question is, is there any way in the `abstract_method` to tell Django to address the calling class (that is, `InheritedClass`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Technical answer :** Well, quite simply yes :

```
def abstract_method(self):
     type(self).objects.filter(..).update(....)
     return self
```

Note that this is Python methods are called with the "calling" object (the object on which the method is invoked) as first parameter, and all attributes lookups will happens on this object and it's class - else inheritance just wouldn't work at all. The only django-specific part here is that Django prevents you from using a ModelManager on a model instance so you need to explicitely get the object's class, which is returned by `type(self)`.

BUT :

**Coding style considerations**

Django recommands that model methods acting on the whole table should belong to the ModelManager (by contrast with methods acting on the current row only which are to be implemented as plain methods), so since your method obviously acts on the whole table it *might* be better as a ModelManager method.

I say "might" because there's a grey area, where updating one row implies updating some other rows too - a typical example is when you have a flag that should always only be set for one single record so you also want to unset it on all other records. There's (of course) not enough context in your question to tell which is the right choice here.

Answer (score -1):

you can just do `self.objects.filter(...).update(..)`

An abstract class just implements methods that are inherited by its concrete class, here `InheritedClass`.  Therefore, everything for methods and fields are available in the inheriting class.

However, for this instance, I would suggest you look at making a custom model manager.  Methods in a model are meant to work with that specific row's fields, whereas managers are intended to work table-wide as described at [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods)

> Define custom methods on a model to add custom “row-level” functionality to your objects. Whereas Manager methods are intended to do “table-wide” things, model methods should act on a particular model instance.

If you have a method doing filtering in a model method, that is a code smell and it belongs in a custom Manager.

Comment: No, Jason. self.objects....is not correct syntax here. See Bruno's answer

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan: the syntax is actually correct (else you'd get a SyntaxError right from the start), the issue is that Django ORM actively prevents accessing a manager via a model instance (raising an AttributeError).

Comment: @Jason : as mentionned above, accessing a manager on a model instance raises an AttributeError, so you really have to use `type(self).objects.whatever()` here. wrt/ custom manager, I wholefully agree that _as a general rule_ table-wide operations should belong to managers or querysets, but there are some grey zones. A typical example would be a 'default' flag that should only be set on one single record at a time, so activating it on an instance should deactivate it on any other instance, which requires accessing the manager from an instance.